# Let $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$ and $x = (x_n) \in \ell^p$. $\hspace{0.1cm}$ Show that $x \in \ell^q$

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, vector-spaces

Let $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$ and $x =  (x_n) \in  \ell^p$. $\hspace{0.1cm}$ Show that $x \in \ell^q$

**Definition:**

$$\ell^p (\mathbb{K})  \equiv \ell^p \colon =  \left\{(\xi_{i}) \in \mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}} \colon \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\xi_i|^p < \infty \right\}$$
*Where $\mathbb{K}$ denotes $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}}:= \{f \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{K} \}$*

Studying some notes from my teacher on Linear Algebra, I have found the previous exercise and I'm interested in doing it. Of the $\ell^p$ spaces, I only know their definition and therefore, it has been difficult for me to apply it to this problem. However, I have been able to verify that the Minkowski inequality and the property of homogeneity for convergent series guarantee that the set $\ell^p$ is really a vector subspace of $\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}}$. I need some help to solve this problem. I appreciate any attempt.

Comment: This is not super fancy. What do you know about convergent series of real numbers? This should just be a standard calculus question.

Comment: The very short version, contained in answers below:  Raising numbers between 0 and 1 to higher powers yields smaller numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $1\leq p\leq q\leq\infty$ and let $(x_{i})_{i}\in\ell_{p}$. Then, as you noted, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}|^{p}<\infty$. This implies, as Ted Shifrin hinted at, that $\lim_{i\to\infty}|x_{i}|\to 0$. In particular, there exists $i_{*}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{i}|<1$ for all $i\geq i_{*}$. It follows that
\begin{equation*} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}|^{q}=\sum_{i=1}^{i_{*}}|x_{i}|^{q}+\sum_{i=i_{*}+1}^{\infty}|x_{i}|^{q}\leq \sum_{i=1}^{i_{*}}|x_{i}|^{q}+\sum_{i=i_{*}+1}^{\infty}|x_{i}|^{p}<\infty\end{equation*}
because $(x_{i})_{i}$ and hence $(x_{i})_{i\geq i_{*}}$ is in $\ell_{p}$ by hypothesis.

Comment: This question has been answered infintely many times on MSE.

Comment: What is your point? Feel free to link to another equivalent answer if you wish.